# How to open new kivy Screen without kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

I need to open a new Screen after click on any button, and close the main screen. Thats possible?

logic:

```
if i click in b4 do > close the MAIN SCREEN and open a new empty screen.
```

i tried some tutorials in internet but i want to do this without use of a kv file.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows= 3

        self.title = Label(text='MAIN SCREEN')
        self.add_widget(self.title)

        self.MainGrid = GridLayout()
        self.MainGrid.cols = 2

        self.b4 = Button(text="#b4")
        self.MainGrid.add_widget(self.b4)
        self.b4.bind(on_press=self.newScreen)

        self.add_widget(self.MainGrid)

    def newScreen(self, instance):
        pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: what is the *main screen*?

Comment: the main screen '-' , the first app screen. that shows the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any Screen so you can't change it, you have a main window. The solution is to set a ScreenManager as a toplevel, add the necessary Screen, and in the first Screen add an object of the Grid class, and make the binding so that it changes the "current" property to the name of the Screen that you want to display

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class Grid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(Grid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 3
        self.title = Label(text="MAIN SCREEN")
        self.add_widget(self.title)
        self.MainGrid = GridLayout()
        self.MainGrid.cols = 2
        self.b4 = Button(text="#b4")
        self.MainGrid.add_widget(self.b4)
        self.add_widget(self.MainGrid)


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.main_screen = Screen(name="main_screen")
        self.new_screen = Screen(name="new_screen")

        self.add_widget(self.main_screen)
        self.add_widget(self.new_screen)

        grid = Grid()
        grid.b4.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)
        self.main_screen.add_widget(grid)

    def change_screen(self, *args):
        self.current = "new_screen"


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```